# Python list all submodules imported from module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

My code starts with the following:

```
from module import *
```

How can I get a list of all `submodules` imported from this module.

For example module has:

```
module.submodule
module.submodule2
module.anothersubmodule
```

I want to get after `from module import *`:

```
[submodule, submodule2, anothersubmodule]
```

(not strings with name of `submodules`, but a list with all `submodules` themselves)

UPD: I understood that I asked about XY problem.
So here's what i'm trying to achieve:
I have a folder called `modules` that will have a bunch of scripts following the same pattern. They will all have a function like `main()`. In my main script i want to import them all and iterate like that:

```
for i in modules:
    i.main(*some_args)
```

Comment: All information about imported modules can be found in `sys.modules`. Also don't use wildcard imports, they can be hard to debug and can cause one or the other surprise.

Comment: That somehow sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the higher level goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I `import *` because i want my script to have pluggable modules, so that i can just edit `__all__` in `__init__.py` and add submodules to modules folder. Then my script will handle all modules using that list.

Answer (score 13):

Use the `pkgutil` module. For example:

```
import pkgutil
import module

modualList = []
for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(module.__path__):
    modualList.append(modname)
```

Comment: thanks! here is a somewhat simpler version:

`import pkgutil; [s[1] for s in list(pkgutil.iter_modules(some_module.__path__))]`

Answer (score 3):

What about [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)?

```
import importlib
import os

directory = './module'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
        continue

    modulename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

    args = [filename, filepath]

    module = importlib.import_module('module.{}'.format(modulename))
    module.main(*args)
```

With 3 differents Python files in `./modules`, all like:

```
def main(*args):
    print('module one: {}'.format(', '.join(args)))
```

It gives:

```
module three: three.py, ./module/three.py
module two: two.py, ./module/two.py
module one: one.py, ./module/one.py
```